# jquery html replace page with $(document).ready code

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to replace html in my site.  The HTML that is getting inserted has a "$(document).ready" function at the bottom of the page.  That code is not getting run when the html gets replaced.  I guess that makes sense because the whole page is not actually loading.  It is just replacing HTML.  What is the best way to make sure this code runs?
Here is the code that is doing the replacing:

```
function procView(url, e) {
    var data = $('.checkout form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Shop/' + url,
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            $('.rightPane').html(result);
            $('#dvSummary').load('/Shop/_summary');
            validateCC();
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert(result.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

It is the .html(result) line.  If it matters, I am using asp.net MVC5.

And here is the document.ready code with the validateCC() function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            alert("out of the function!");
            //$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden, .data-val-ignore" });
            function validateCC() {
                alert("in the function!");
                $('#CardNum').validateCreditCard(function (result) {
                    $("#CardNum").attr('class', 'data-val-ignore');
                    if (result.card_type != null) {
                        $("#CardNum").addClass(result.card_type.name);
                    }
                    if (result.card_type != null && $("#CardNum").val().length == result.card_type.valid_length) {
                        $("#CardNum").addClass("valid");
                    }
                },
                { accept: ['visa', 'mastercard', 'amex', 'discover'] });
            }
        });
```

Neither of those alerts run for me.  In fact I get: "ReferenceError: validateCC is not defined".

Comment: Try placing a `console.log` or `alert` in the other code.

Comment: Yes, what is the problem to put `alert` at the beginning of function?

Answer (score 0):

With the Ajax function you know when something is correctly executed, therefore, once you have loaded the content using the `.html()` function you could simply call the function you want to be executed.

Let's say you have this on your second document:

```
<div class="test">Hello</div>
<script>
    function doSomething() {
        $(document).find(".test").text("Hello World");
    }
</script>
```

in your success function you could then do something like this:

```
success: function (result) {
    $('.rightPane').html(result);
    $('#dvSummary').load('/Shop/_summary');
    doSomething();
}
```

To be honest I am not sure 100% this will work but you can try.

Comment: Tried it.  This is not working.  I'll add my function up above.

Comment: May I ask you what does your `result` variable contain? What do you get if you print out its content? And is the content loaded inside your `$('.rightPane')`?

Comment: The content does get loaded into the rightPane.  The result is a bunch of html with some javascript at the bottom in a "Scripts" section.

Comment: what if you remove the `$(document).ready(function() {});` and simply define the function?

Comment: So I learned that you cannot stick "sections" in partial pages.  So that must be why the code is not running.  How do I get around this?